# How Do I get a newly created method to work in the rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've created a fairly simple new method in one of my models. However, when I go to the rails console to test it, I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method 'get' for #<Class:0x3a5032fc>
```

I have saved the code, closed the rails console and then restarted, but I still get the NoMethod

```
class Race <ActiveRecord::Base
  def get(race_date,track_name,race_number)
    Race.where(:date =>race_date, :race_nbr => race_number, :track_id => (Track.where(:track_code => track_name)))
  end
end
```

In the console, I enter the following:

```
Race.get("2011-12-04", "BEL", 1)
```

which yields the `NoMethodError:undefined method 'get'`.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You defined an instance method of the class Race. Maybe you would have defined a class method like:

```
def self.get(race_date, track_name, race_number)
    track = Track.where(:track_code => track_name)
    Race.where(:date => race_date, :race_nbr => race_number, :track_id => track)
end
```

Then you can use `Race.get`.

Comment: I would separate out the `track` into a local variable, just to make the line shorter. But besides that, great answer.

Comment: Ryan - What exactly do you mean by separating track into a local variable.  Could you give me an example of what you mean.

Comment: @Mutuelinvestor Look at the updated answer again. just set `track = Track.where(:track_code => track_name)` and then pass that in to the `where` statement in the `Race` query so it's cleaner code.

Answer (score 4):

@lucapette got it right; you need to create a class method.  Below is another way that you can define class methods.  In large projects where you're defining a large number of class methods, it can be a cleaner way of organizing code, but that opinion is purely subjective.

```
class << self
  def get(race_date,track_name,race_number)
    Race.where(:date => race_date, 
               :race_nbr => race_number, 
               :track_id => (Track.where(:track_code => track_name)))
  end
end
```

Everything defined within `class << self` becomes a class method.

Another option is to use a scope.

```
scope :get, 
      lambda { |race_date, track_name, race_number| 
               Race.where(:date => race_date, 
                          :race_nbr => race_number, 
                          :track_id => (Track.where(:track_code => track_name))) }
```

This last solution looks a little unwieldy as a scope, so it's probably best to use a class method in this case instead of a scope.  Also, I prefer scopes that have descriptive names, but I guess that would apply to method names as well.

Answer (score 4):

After two great answers, I feel like something else should be stated:

If your console was already launched, it won't guess you've added some code so you have to reload.

Yo do this, simply type:

```
reload!
```

in the console (=no need to CTRL-C).

Comment: That's a great point.  If you're editing outside of the console, this is a must.  I don't know how I missed that.  +1